# Can I use rapply over a nested list of model objects

Tags: r

Can I use `rapply` to drill down into a list (the structure of which is unknown; might be nested or might not) to extract some information?  For example, I have a list of model objects, one element of which is also a list of model objects. Can I run a function on all at once?

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10))
names(df) <- c("X","Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4")

modlist <- list(
  m1 = lm(Y1 ~ X, data = df),
  m2 = lm(Y2 ~ X, data = df),
  m3 = list(
    m3.1 = lm(Y3 ~ X, data = df),
    m3.2 = lm(Y4 ~ X, data = df)
  )
)
```

extract the intercept from each relationship:

```
getcoef <- function(x) coefficients(x)[1]

getcoef(modlist[[1]])
# works fine

rapply(modlist, getcoef, classes = "lm", how = "replace")
# returns unlisted model objects!???
```

Comment: @jdharrison that didn't appear to work. I edited to show a simpler function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just redefine your `getcoef` function and use `lapply`:

```
> getcoef <- function(x) if(inherits(x, "lm")) coefficients(x)[1] else lapply(x, getcoef)
> str(lapply(modlist, getcoef))
List of 3
 $ m1: Named num -0.143
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "(Intercept)"
 $ m2: Named num -0.11
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "(Intercept)"
 $ m3:List of 2
  ..$ m3.1: Named num 0.0743
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "(Intercept)"
  ..$ m3.2: Named num -0.577
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "(Intercept)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` and a recursive function:

```
recSummary <- function(x, ...){
  if("lm" %in% class(x)){
    summary(x, ...)
  }else{
    lapply(x, recSummary, ...)
  }
}

lapply(modlist, recSummary)
```

`rapply` appears to unclass the result of `summary` when `how = replace`

UPDATE:
With your ammended question:

```
getcoef <- function(x) coefficients(x)[1]
recSummary <- function(x, func = summary, ...){
  if("lm" %in% class(x)){
    func(x, ...)
  }else{
    lapply(x, recSummary, func, ...)
  }
}

lapply(modlist, recSummary, func = getcoef)

$m1
(Intercept) 
0.1913376 

$m2
(Intercept) 
-0.3930023 

$m3
$m3$m3.1
(Intercept) 
0.1184415 

$m3$m3.2
(Intercept) 
0.01367811
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you wanted. I can do it with rapply but I then get duplicates so this seems much simpler:

```
> out2 <- unlist(modlist)
> head(names(out2))
[1] "m1.coefficients.(Intercept)" "m1.coefficients.X"          
[3] "m1.residuals.1"              "m1.residuals.2"             
[5] "m1.residuals.3"              "m1.residuals.4"             

> out2[ grepl("coefficients\\.\\(Intercept", names(out2)) ]
$`m1.coefficients.(Intercept)`
[1] -0.1408831

$`m2.coefficients.(Intercept)`
[1] -0.01388696

$`m3.m3.1.coefficients.(Intercept)`
[1] 0.310378

$`m3.m3.2.coefficients.(Intercept)`
[1] -0.4699532
```